# Python 3.4 Installing bs4- Running Python2 not Python3

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup

Today is a terrible day for me. I'm so frustrated because I've spent the last 4 hours trying to install `beautifulsoup4`. I've searched every tutorial I can get my hands on.
It is installed on my computer, but when I do `import bs4` on the shell it gives me this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4
  File "C:\Python34\lib\bs4\__init__.py", line 48
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can do? it tells me to run a command but it doesn't tell me how to run it.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: in your command line https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation from the url: Beautiful Soup is packaged as Python 2 code. When you install it for use with Python 3, it’s automatically converted to Python 3 code. If you don’t install the package, the code won’t be converted. There have also been reports on Windows machines of the wrong version being installed. 

If you get the SyntaxError “Invalid syntax” on the line ROOT_TAG_NAME = u'[document]', you need to convert the Python 2 code to Python 3. You can do this either by installing the package:
$ python3 setup.py install

Comment: if you are own windows, you should use the console: run "cmd"

Comment: I installed it by getting it off http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.4/ and then I did a bunch of stuff. I'm on the verge of tears right now so I don't know what happened after that. I know it's installed on my computer though. I did "pip install beatifulsoup4" but it wasn't exactly that. It doesn't work when I try it now...but my cmd told me that I installed it.

Comment: Ale how do I even do that? I see $ and I'm on windows, not linux

Comment: Hard for us to troubleshoot "did a bunch of stuff" and "don't know what happened". `pip install beautifulsoup4` always has worked for me, but I've never tried it on Windows—what do you mean by "but it wasn't exactly that"?

Comment: @switch87 I'm not sure what you mean when you say I need to put that in my cmd. whatever I type in it tells me that 2to3 is invalid syntax

Comment: @myersjustinc It tells me invalid syntax for the word "install" now

Comment: To be honest, I think you need to find someone at your location to fix this problem for you. I have no clue what you did, and because of that, I don't know why your installation is broken.

Comment: @user3658033: That sounds like you're still in Python and not at your actual shell. Does your prompt start with `>>>`? (If so, run `exit()` and try again.)

Comment: sorry @myersjustinc now I'm there and it's installled. It says "requirement already satisfied....."

Comment: If somebody wants to skype with me to help please let me know

Comment: So `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4` (to undo whatever you've already done) and then try `pip install beautifulsoup4` again.

Comment: @myersjustinc I LOVE YOU. thank you so much it worked :D

Comment: Glad to hear it! (In general, downloading packages directly from websites can cause some weird problems, especially when it comes to dependencies and different Python versions. `pip` is really useful.)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the question. In the folder where bs4 is located (you could download bs4 in you work folder also), run :

> 2to3 -w bs4

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this easy on you (If your using a 3x version of Python)

1. Go to your Python folder
2. Open the scripts folder
3. On the white space hold shift, right click and then open a command window
4. Type "pip install beautifulsoup4"

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it appears to be an issue with the latest release of beautifulsoup being installed via the TAR file.

I went back and got version 4.1.3 and it is now working for me in Python 3.4

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing beautifulsoup4_4.5.1 on Python 3.4 via copying the .tar file. What worked for me was uninstalling the beautifulsoup and installing it again using the pip install method. If installation is successful, you will find bs4 in the list of installed modules. Here are the steps:

1. c:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe uninstall beautifulsoup4
2. c:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install beautifulsoup4
3. c:\Python34\python.exe
4. help('modules')
5. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Got the following error multiple times.
"'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (python setup.py install) or by running 2to3 (2to3 -w bs4).'"

**This is what i did. (On MAC)**
Step 1: Install python 2.7.(I had trouble installing BS4 with python3, so I use the latest version of serie 2 for installation.)

Step 2: Install latest version of beautiful soup. Then relocate the downloaded folder to somewhere easily accessible.

Step 3: Open TERMINAL and type in "cd ***" (note: DON'T include the quote. Also, *** in this case refer to the directory of the beautiful soup folder. If you don't know the directory of the folder, simply drag the folder to the terminal and you will get it!)

Step 4: Type "python setup.py install" in terminal(note: same thing. no quote)

Step 5: Wait for it to finish. Open IDLE/Python Shell

Step 6: Type "import os"
Step 7: Type "os.chdir(***)" (Note: same directory like the above)
Step 8: Type "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"

AND you're good to go! GL