# Issue with bs4, claiming I am using python 3 to run the python 2 version of bs4

Tags: python

I am receiving an error, 
 'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
                                                                                                       ^
Help appreciated

Comment: How did you install bs4 ? Seems that you either installed bs4 under python2, or are running the your py2 code using py3.

Comment: I installed it by using pip install beautifulsoup4 in the python 3 directory, I have also tried dragging the file downloaded off the website into the directory and then using 2to3 but it gives me an error, claiming 2to3 is not recognized

Comment: linux or windows?

Comment: Can you try `pip uninstall beautifulsoup4` and `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` ? If you use `pip`, by default it will install it under the python 2 environment. You should either symlink `pip3` to `pip` or always use `pip3 install...`

Comment: Ok this is weird, I tried pip remove beautifulsoup4 and removed is unrecognized so I tried pip uninstall beautifulsoup4 and it says there are no files found to uninstall.

Comment: My bad, should be `pip uninstall`. I edited my comment. What happens when you `pip3 install` ? and which OS are you using ?

Comment: win10, I managed to uninstall it, but using pip3 it says requirement already satisfied! Ahhh!

Comment: Just uninstalled and reinstalled with pip3, no luck

Comment: Maybe it's my code, should I post it?

Comment: Sure, add a snippet if that can help. How do you run your code ? There's clearly a missmatch between python2 and 3 somewhere.
Have you checked this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730053/python-3-4-installing-bs4-running-python2-not-python3 ?

Comment: I did check that post, I'm running my code in pycharm, using the python 3 interpreter.

Comment: How do I format the code?

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/asia').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')

print(soup.prettify())`

Comment: eh whatever I am running out of ideas